# I have loaded an animation with this code, how can I get 5th frame of animation?

Tags: processing

I have loaded an animation with this code:

```
images = loadImages("Animation_data/movie", ".jpg", 134);
```

How would you display the 5th frame of the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `images` is a `PImage[]` you can just use index 4: `image(images[4],0,0);`

For more info see [array access[]](https://processing.org/reference/arrayaccess.html)

Additionally, I've developed a Processing library that makes it easy to load and display image sequences called [Image Sequence Player](https://github.com/hirschandmann/image-sequence-player) and it has been used on a few commercial projects at [Hirsch & Mann](https://www.hirschandmann.com/work/)

[image: Image Sequence Player processing library demo displaying a hand drawn sequence by James Patterson]

(Image sequence by [James Patterson](http://presstube.com/hello/))